# Warning: /Volumes/macOS Base System/AppleInternal/Library/Extensions does not exist all files copied to /Volumes/System/Volumes/macOS Base System/

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina

I have a problem with a brand new 2020 13” MacBook Pro, running Catalina, unfortunately, this is not a new problem.  It began in December 2018 when the recovery partition on my 2011 MBA got messed up during one of my attempts at performing a clean, USB install of macOS High Sierra.  As a result, the install is always based on “using product at distance 5” which positions the startup volume in /Volumes/System/  or /Volumes/System/Volumes/  instead of /Volumes/, where it belongs. This problem has occurred on the previous eight MBA’s I have purchased and returned in the past two years along with this new 2020 MBP. The following information is from a recent install log of macOS Sierra, which I have included because “using product at distance 5” began here.

Edit: Perhaps the easier question ... Is there a script that will load the MacOS Base System file so I can delete it on my 2011 MBA (source of problem).

```
Sep 14 19:28:14 MacBook-Air osinstallersetupd[547]: Using product <OSISInstallMediaProduct> based on media at /Volumes/OS X Install ESD at distance 5<br />
Sep 14 19:28:14 MacBook-Air osinstallersetupd[547]: Using product PKSecureNetEnabledProduct <file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/macOS%20Install%20Data/> at distance 5
```

I just discovered the following, which shows /Volumes/macOS Base System being copied/moved to /Volumes/System/Volumes/macOS Base System/ because Volumes/macOS Base System/(and associated files) do not exist. After a month of sending logs, pictures, etc. to the engineers at Apple Support, they continue to claim; “this is expected behavior. The information doesn’t show anything mounted incorrectly.  The data they are viewing is showing the MacBook Pro operating as expected”, so I continue to look for a solution. Reinstallation of macOS does not copy or move macOS Base System from /System/Volumes/Data back to /Volumes; I believe this could be due to a file in “SharedSupport”.  Thank you!

```
---- Begin System Software Update Arming -----\
Ensuring /Volumes/macOS Base System's caches are up to date. 
Warning: /Volumes/macOS Base System/AppleInternal/Library/Extensions: No such file or directory. 
Warning: /Volumes/macOS Base System/Library/Apple/System/Library/Extensions: No such file or.  directory
Note: /Volumes/macOS Base System/System/Library/Kernels/kernel: No such file or directory. 
Primary kext cache does not need update.  
CSFDE property cache does not need update.  
Localized EFI Login resources do not need update.  
Mounting helper partition...  
Looking for missing files. 
Copying files used by the booter. 
creating com.apple.Boot.plist data with UUID B392677C-67A5-4583-B8DF-DEB7B13F0E6C.  
copying /Volumes/macOS BaseSystem/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.corestorage/EncryptedRoot.plist.wipekey to /System/Volumes/Data/macOS Install Data/Locked Files/Boot Files. 
copying /Volumes/macOS Base System/usr/standalone/i386/EfiLoginUI/ to /System/Volumes/Data/macOS Install Data/Locked Files/Boot Files.   
copying /Volumes/macOS Base System/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.corestorage/EFILoginLocalizations to /System/Volumes/Data/macOS Install Data/Locked Files/Boot Files.    
copying /Volumes/macOS Base System/System/Library/PrelinkedKernels/prelinkedkernel to /System/Volumes/Data/macOS Install Data/Locked Files/Boot Files.    
Copying files read before the booter runs. 
Moving aside old label. 
Copying new booter. 
Activating new booter  
Activating files used by the booter.  
Activating files used before the booter runs.  
Successfully updated disk1s2/macOS Install Data/Locked Files/Boot Files.  
Rolling back any incomplete updates. 
 
Sep 13 23:22:43 MacBook-Pro OSInstaller[644]: Finding disk for productURL: /macOS Install Data.  
Sep 13 23:22:43 MacBook-Pro OSInstaller[644]: Using product <OSProduct: 0x7fa16ed59900> at distance 5. 

Sep 30 Install

Sep 30 16:27:17 MacBook-Pro OSInstaller[665]: Using product <OSProduct: 0x7fa04f31f320> at distance 5.
```

Comment: 1. You can't run High Sierra on a 2020 Mac. 2. Why not just use Internet Recovery, then you can simply wipe the drive & start over, with Catalina? 3. You appear [though I may be wrong, I've never seen logs like that] to be trying to install an OS onto the installer partition itself, which cannot be done.

Comment: Are you reinstalling the OS onto this new Mac? If so, why? It sounds like there's a problem with the installer process you're using. Have you really returned 8 MBAs because of this?

Comment: Sierre /High Sierra files from 2011 MBA - where this problem began. Reinstallation does not change anything because the problem originates on/from my 2011 MBA. I understand this sounds whacky, but I have an issue with a shared file... and... yes, I have returned 8 MBA's because of this very same issue and about to add 1 MBP, as Apple Support is useless. I really want to resolve this issue as my 2011 MBA is almost useless.

Comment: It sounds like your method is wrong - see https://support.apple.com/HT204904 & start from Cmd/Opt/R. Wipe the drive first step once you're in the Recovery environment. Reinstalling should not by itself migrate any data. You can do that as a separate step if you have issues with a backup. If you have issues with a single file, try to bypass any backup structure & just email it to yourself.

Comment: The above information was copied from the original setup/installation file. This did not occur during a recovery installation, although that doesn't help either. The problem is a shared file from my 2011 MacBook Air, which has the same problem.  Thank you!

Comment: The problem **cannot** be any file from any other Mac, because at the point of System installation, no other Mac is involved. You really need to clarify your method.

Comment: I will clarify.. there is a shared online file that is downloaded.during installation/recovery. etc.  I was not asking for assistance or guidance on recovery procedures... I know them, all.  I was hoping someone might be knowledgeable about shared files, because I am not able to locate it.

Comment: Sorry, that is no clearer. macOS BaseSystem only exists as a temporary 'live' mounted volume whilst you are booted to recovery. It exists only in RAM. You really need to tell us precisely what you are trying to achieve, not how you think you should achieve it. As it stands, this seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Tetsujin, if you don't understand the issue, then you obviously can't provide any assistance.  At this point, this MacBook has more issue than I am willing to deal with and am returning it; so reply or not.

Comment: I am requesting you provide more clarity. Your question as asked makes no real sense. The additional detail you provided makes it even less clear what you are trying to do. You have now provided no more info at all & are merely questioning my competence. That's the point at which I say, "Good luck, you're on your own". If you can have issues with 8 different Macs, I think it's fairly safe to say the fault is not with the Mac, but as you will not provide detail, only argument, I'm out.